# What are the General reservations against using StartsWith() routine in Java (More details below)

Tags: java, enums, startswith

I have been advised by my colleagues not to use StartsWith() method in java when comparing say against the enum values. Reason being if we add anything in Enum which starts with similar String & want them to be handled differently, it might go off the radar with startsWith as it will be accepting the new value & silently passing as well. Though i agree to this in principle , but its a case specific thing. Are there any General reservations against usage of StartsWith() in java.

Comment: could you be more specific and provide sample code?

Comment: Why exactly are you using `startsWith()`? In general, you would use it only when you need it. It's not clear from your question why you need it.

Comment: Wait... `.startsWith()` on _enum_s??

Comment: Reservations? Absolutely! Classification of enumerated values should be done explicitly rather than using the coincidence of the string representation. Enums can have multiple properties. Add the properties that allow categorization explicitly and save yourself a bunch of heartache.

Comment: Are you sure? It's like .indexof(...)==0

Comment: Thanks Bob.That Makes sense. Pretty much.
-fge .. yes using string representation
-Rohit .. i was making use of its string representation property to see if my enum value is one among a particular group & then taking some action.. better approach would be to have a function exposed which does it for me after it accepts a string & see if it matches with any of the enum's string in the Group. That will help me to save problems later as Bob mentioned.

@Andrea yes i am sure & yes its pretty much like that but i guess indexOf will have degraded performance due to time complexity in worst case.

Comment: @dstronczak There is nothing much to describe here. Bob's comment & my reply pretty much sums it. Will be more clearer from next time around. Newbie

Comment: @BobDalgleish Thanks, I think you have answered well, I also have read [the enum explaining](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and I have learned something new.. Thanks again.